# libreoffice writer Find-bar fontsize

Tags: libreoffice-writer

I'm using Libre-Office writer  ( 6.4.7.2) on ubuntu 20.04 .

I need to find a way to increase the size of the fonts in the Find-bar (where I enter the search terms, so I can more easily see the search terms as I type them).

My display resolution is 3840x2160 (4k) in 16:9, and the default font for the search-terms field of the Find-bar is too small.